# Using a custom offset alias in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

After implementing a custom frequency in pandas by subclassing `DateOffset`, is it possible to "register" an offset alias for that frequency so that the alias can be used in built-in pandas functions such as `date_range` and `resample`?

For example, suppose I implement a custom twice-monthly frequency:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset, CacheableOffset

class TwiceMonthly(DateOffset, CacheableOffset):
    def apply(self, other):
        # Some date logic here

    @property
    def rule_code(self):
        return 'TM'
```

Now, instead of using `TwiceMonthly()` everywhere, I want to use the offset alias TM.

```
# Suppose s is a time series
s.resample('TM', how='sum')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible right now unfortunately. Aliasing is static. 
It would be a good feature to add though. Please check back on github (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2085). Additional feedback or a PR would be appreciated.

Comment: I created an issue in case someone comes along and wants to do it: http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2089

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and found my solution in the documentation of pandas here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#combining-aliases

You can combine aliases in Pandas, if you recorded your Date in a different time interval than proposed.